# Extracting URLs from multiple pages of archive.org?

Tags: url

Usually i search for books at archive.org,i find them one by one,open each one in a new tab,and when there are 30 tabs i open new chrome windows.Each tab has a URL like 
https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.12237 .So at the end i got some chrome windows,each with 30 tabs.I want a list of the URLs of the PDF files which are available at each tab(1 PDF is at each tabs).Now,how could i do it as easy as possible,and for free?
Best,

Comment: What have you tried? In what langage? What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: Some soft wares like WEB DATA EXTRACTOR,but i think Scrapy would work.I want the list to download the PDFs using download manager,and i have not work with any languages.

Comment: I think you're on the wrong website. SO is for programming question, not "what software can I use?". If you're not planning to do any programming, please delete your question as its off topic.